# How to pass "LIVE" data with django sessions?

Tags: django, session

I have a long task to process in django admin's [response_change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change) .  It takes a few good minutes so I would like to make a progress indicator. I store the progress into sessions but when I read the session from a different view (which is called on a timer from JS every 300ms) the session does not contain the updated progress (which I set in the long task). It always has what the session had when the long task ended last time.

Official docs say "You can read it and write to request.session at any point in your view. You can edit it multiple times.". So why isn't it working ?

Update: the accepted answer indeed answers this question. But I still cannot apply it to my actual case. Yes, between 2 regular views it works just fine, but between admin's response_change and a regular view it doesn't. It's definitely the same session because session_key, _auth_user_id, _auth_user_hash are the same in both threads. If you have any tips please leave them in comments.Thanks

Update2: Setting the Session engine to file fixed it ! WHY ???
It's not a speed issue since the database session engine does not even work in debug mode, where I take breaks of several minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is not saved until the end of the request/when the server sends back the response. You can save the session yourself with `request.session.save()` Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.base_session.BaseSessionManager.save

Comment: That was it.  TBH it still does not work in the admin's response_change, but I was able to test it in 2 regular views, and save fixes it.  No parameters needed. Thanks a lot .